# Getting property with MVVM, binding and template

Tags: wpf, templates, binding, mvvm

I using binding to transfer data from ViewModel to Template, but I want to transfer data from Teample to ViewModel.

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding List}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding Content}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

I want to get (with binding) TabIndex of currently creating TabItem.
How I can do that?

Comment: can you please post your code for your List property you bind to.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand which property you are trying to pass to the ViewModel from your template. But basically if you'd like to pass a value from your template to your view model you would do that with a "OneWayToSource" or "TwoWay" binding mode.

If I undestood correctly and what you are tyring to pass to your view model is the index of the currently selected TabItem, you can do it in the following way -

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding List}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectedIndex={Binding SelectedIndex, Mode="OneWayToSource">
```

(Notice that there should also be a SelectedIndex dependency property on your view model)

Although according to MSDN the binding mode of this property is "TwoWay" by default, so you don't have to specify the binding mode.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedindex.aspx

Comment: Ok, but I need TabIndex of TabItem too. How Can I get TabIndex of currently creating TabItem?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand. What do you mean by "currently creating TabItem"?

Comment: I binding ItemsSource, so I use `listOfTab.Add(tab1);` to add new TabItem and I want to get Index from this item.

Comment: So what you want is to keep an updated property of the index of the last added item? You said at the beginning that you are trying to pass data from the template to your view model, so how does that get along with what you are saying?

Comment: Because I add new TabItem with binding to template.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to hook into the ICollectionView exposed because you've set IsSynchronisedToCurrentItem to true.

UNTESTED EXAMPLE

```
public ObservableCollection<object> List {get; set;}

public int SelectedIndex
{
    get { return CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(List).CurrentPosition; }
    set { CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(List).MoveCurrentTo(value); }
}
```

Then, you can bind to the SelectedIndex property in your ViewModel.

If this doesn't work, bind Directly to a ListCollectionView in your ViewModel instead of a plain ObservableCollection, and substitute MyListCollectionView for CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(List) in the above code.